# Can a warlock pact be inherited

Tags: games, dungeons-and-dragons

Either in the sense that the pact Is passed down from parent to child or in the sense that a parent could make a pact for an unborn child without their permission?

(I understand that ultimately its all up to the DM, but has there been any reference to this in official wotc stuff)

Comment: Do you mean the [Dungeons and Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(film)) movie, or the tabletop RPG?  If it's for the RPG, your question belongs in the [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: Questions about the fictional content of science fiction and fantasy roleplaying games are permissible here. Since this isn’t just a mechanics question, but actually asking about how magic works in the D&D universe, it’s on-topic.

Comment: Yeah, I understood from the DM comment that this is asking about any tie-in materials that might establish a setting canon, not the game mechanics.

Comment: I agree the question isn't necessarily off-topic here, but the OP is more likely to get an answer on the dedicated site IMO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about game rules.

Comment: @Buzz From my understanding the OP is asking for an IU reason not about game rules. It would help though if the OP could [edit] their question to clear this up.

Comment: As a point of practical interest, my work blocks all gaming related sites, including the RPG stack.  However, I can freely use this site.  Something like this, if at work, I'd HAVE to use SF&F.

Answer (score 1):

In the Dungeon Master's Guide, page 263, it says:

> As the Dungeon Master, you aren't limited by the rules in the *Player's Handbook*, the guidelines in this book, or the selection of monsters in the *Monster Manual*. You can let your imagination run wild.

On the following pages, some examples of rule changes are given, including modifying classes.

This means that if your group decides that it would be cool if warlock pacts could be inherited, then, yes, they could be. Your DM, as the 'Master of Rules', has the final say on whether it is possible and under what conditions.

EDIT: If you just look at the rules as written, the answer would have to be NO. On page 107 of the Player's Handbook, it is clearly stated that "At 1st level, you have struck a bargain with an otherworldly being of your choice." Nothing is mentioned of others being able to strike such a bargain for you or passing it on to you. In any case, that would not be "of your choice". Hence, a house rule would be required to allow this.

Comment: I've downvoted. Typically, this isn't seen as a useful answer even on the RPG Stack Exchange, and on this site we further focus on fiction, not game rules. Besides, the poster specifically tried to preempt this sort of answer.

Comment: #Adamant: I have edited my answer to reflect that.